# U22.04 How to set the network card to STA+P2P (GO) mode？

Tags: golang, p2p

My computer inf:
SYS VER   : 22.04
WIFI CARD : AX201
iw list :
Supported interface modes:
* IBSS
* managed
* AP
* AP/VLAN
* monitor
* P2P-client
*** P2P-GO**
* P2P-device

Comment: [1] I use wpa_cli p2p_group_add OK

Comment: [2] wifi p2p go create OK

Comment: [3] my phone connect ok

Comment: [4] FAIL , my phone dhcp work, can't get ip

Comment: Please add more details on your operating system, hardware, which commands you tried, what didn't work and which error messages you got.